# Mule:Magento connector: get-product operation bug

Tags: magento, soap, mule, anypoint-studio

I am trying to get product info from magneto via magneto connector in mule USING GET-PRODUCT OPERATION, but I am getting this error: `Product not exists`even though tested via SOAP UI and worked perfectly.
After a long search I have found the issue:

- request via SOAP UI:

  ```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <soapenv:Header/>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <urn:catalogProductInfo soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
           <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
           <productId xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
           <storeView xsi:type="xsd:string"></storeView>
           <attributes xsi:type="urn:catalogProductRequestAttributes">
              <attributes xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
               </attributes>
           <additional_attributes xsi:type="urn:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]">
              </additional_attributes>
           </attributes>
           <identifierType xsi:type="xsd:string"/>
       </urn:catalogProductInfo>
    </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
  ```
- request via magneto connector:

  ```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns1:catalogProductInfo xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
           <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string"></sessionId>
           <product xsi:type="xsd:string"></product>
           <storeView xsi:type="xsd:string" xsi:nil="true"/>
           <attributes href="#id0"/>
           <productIdentifierType xsi:type="xsd:string"></productIdentifierType>
       </ns1:catalogProductInfo>
     <multiRef xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns2="urn:Magento" id="id0" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="ns2:catalogProductRequestAttributes">
      <attributes soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array">
       <attributes xsi:type="xsd:string"></attributes>
      </attributes>
      <additional_attributes soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[0]" xsi:type="soapenc:Array"/>
    </multiRef>
   </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
  ```

the difference is in the `<product>/<productId>` tag.

Any ideas on how to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue: it's in the magento_v2_soap.wsdl of the magento connector file where in the `catalogProductInfoRequest` the `<part name="product" type="xsd:string"/>`needs to be changed to `<part name="productId" type="xsd:string"/>` I have made the change in  [gitHub](https://github.com/mulesoft/magento-connector) but I don't have write access... so what I did is I made the change downloaded and installed in mule.