# Magento connector in maven mule project

Tags: maven, mule, anypoint-studio

I have came across [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34453109/mulemagento-connector-get-product-operation-bug/34544516#34544516) when using the magneto connector, I have fixed it in the [gitHub](http://httphttps://github.com/mulesoft/magento-connector) repository(but I don't think it was merged yet) and works perfect in my mule project, but when using the magneto connector in a maven mule project the error shows up again? what's wrong? what do I need to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Maven you will need to install it into your local repository or host it in your own Maven repo. You can simply install it locally by running `mvn install` in a command line. You probably should change the version in the pom of the connector and then reference the new version in the dependency section of your pom in the Mule application using the connector